# how to call getUserMedia() in Flutter Inappwebview library?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) version: `5.5.0+5`.
Currently, I want to load https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ with flutter_inappwebview on Android. When the user clicks the `Open camera` button, InAppWebview will display a popup request permission in InAppWebview like other browsers (e.g. Google Chrome).

[image: chrome_browser]

In this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), `getUserMedia()` is required, but I don't know how to use it where.

This is my code.

```
InAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest: "https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/",
     initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      )
    ),
)
```

When The user clicks "Open camera" button, An exception is thrown:

```
D/CameraExtImplXiaoMi(21761): initCameraDevice: 1
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761): allocate: manager.openCamera: 
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761): java.lang.SecurityException: validateClientPermissionsLocked:1253: Caller "com.example.demo.stag.debug" (PID 11056, UID 21761) cannot open camera "1" without camera permission
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1268)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:715)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:961)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraForUid(CameraManager.java:982)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:820)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at WV.EW.startCaptureMaybeAsync(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-609923033:60)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761): Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: validateClientPermissionsLocked:1253: Caller "com.example.demo.stag.debug" (PID 11056, UID 21761) cannot open camera "1" without camera permission (code 1)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2440)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2410)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2393)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2335)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.ICameraService$Stub$Proxy.connectDevice(ICameraService.java:669)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:691)
E/cr_VideoCapture(21761):   ... 4 more
```

how to call `getUserMedia()` in Flutter Inappwebview library?

Comment: it's seems like you haven't added any camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist

Comment: You will also need to ask for camera permission during runtime before invoking the getUserMedia logic.

Comment: @JaiminRaval I added camera permission in `AnroidManifest.xml`

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

Comment: please checkout this package to handle permission :- https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler